# HTML Loads an empty JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an HTML page that loads an external JS file, observing how Jquery is loaded, I figured I needed to just load the JS in a script tag, however, it keeps doing absolutely nothing.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina senza titolo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Generate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          generate(1);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div id = "Top" style = "text-align:left">
        </div>
        <div id = "UI" style = "float: left; width: 400px; height: 200px;">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the External js file Generate.js:

```
 function Generate(num) {

    var roomType = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    var vertOriz = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    var i, j, x, y;

    if (roomType <= 10) {
        i = 10;
        j = 10;
    }else
    if (roomType > 10 && roomType <= 18) {
        if (vertOriz == 1) {
            i = 10;
            j = 20;
        } else {
            i = 20;
            j = 10;
        }
    }else
    if (roomType > 18) {
        i = 20;
        j = 20;
    }

    $("#UI").append("<table id = 'Room" + num + "'></table>");
    for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {
        $("#Room" + num).append("<tr id = y" + y + "></tr>");
        for (x = 0; x < j; x++) {
            if(y == 0){

                if(x == 0){
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9487</td>");
                }else
                if(x == (j - 1)){
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9491</td>");
                }else{
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9473</td>");
                }
            }else
            if (y == (i - 1)) {

                if (x == 0) {
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9495</td>");
                } else
                if (x == (j - 1)) {
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9499</td>");
                } else {
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9473</td>");
                }
            } else
            if (y > 0 && y < (i - 1)) {

                if (x == 0 || x == (j - 1)) {
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#9475</td>");
                } else {
                    $("#y" + y).append("<td id = x" + x + ">&#32</td>");
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

What could possibly be the problem? I'm trying to run it on IE

Comment: "**A simple typographical error**" .. flagged.

Comment: ...how did I missed that...

Answer (score 6):

As you have defined you function in general.js as Generate(Num)..so take care G is capital and you are calling function as generate(1) which is not correct.

Please call function with name `Generate(1)` instead of generate(1);